# Allowing User and Client access to route, Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, authentication, routes, middleware, laravel-passport

I have a route that is used by another application **and** by users, it needs to be secured.

I would like to restrict access to only the Authenticated Users **OR** Authenticated Application Clients.

Is there a way to allow both types of access? Or should I create a separate endpoint for both, with the users using a route with 'auth' middleware and the clients using a route with 'client' middleware?

Comment: How are you currently discerning the differently authenticated users? that's the key question.

Comment: At the moment any route that is secured and accessed by a User uses 'auth:api' middleware. They must be logged in to access the route. Any routes that are accessed by Application Clients (so other API's) use 'client' middleware like so - https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#client-credentials-grant-tokens